# Error encoding/decoding already Unicode object python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

Im using Python2.7

I have an unicode string like this:

```
s = u'Rub\xc3\xa9n'
```

I would like printing this:

```
print convert(s)
Rubén
```

I tried directly printing in several ways, but with not success:

```
print y
RubÃ©n
print y.enconde('utf-8')
RubÃ©n
print y.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
  return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in    position 3-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know the form in which I declared the string is not the best, but other scripts are giving that format.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Unicode string that was mis-decoded as `latin1` or a similar encoding such as `windows-1252`, but was really `utf8`:

```
>>> s = 'Rub\xc3\xa9n'.decode('latin1')
>>> s
u'Rub\xc3\xa9n'
```

It should have been decoded as:

```
>>> s = 'Rub\xc3\xa9n'.decode('utf8')
>>> s
u'Rub\xe9n'
>>> print s
Rubén
```

If you don't have control of how the string was generated, you can undo the problem with:

```
>>> print u'Rub\xc3\xa9n'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Rubén
```